# Attributing CSS class to element

Tags: html, css

Assuming I wanted to attribute the `text-shadow: green;` attribute to every `<h2>` element occouring inside an element with the classes `.dark` and `ux-banner`what CSS code would achieve this?

```
 <div class="dark ux-banner">
      <div class="the attributed classes of this element will vary">
           <h2>TARGET THIS ELEMENT
           </h2>
      </div>
 </div>
```

As in the above example `<h2>` element will be wrapped in a `<div>` with varying classes attributed to it.

What would be the best way to apply the `text-shadow: green;` property to the `<h2>` element when occouring within elements that have the `.dark` and `ux-banner` classes attributed without making reference to the `<div>` immediately surrounding the `<h2>` element

Answer (score 12, accepted):

I believe you're looking for:

```
.dark.ux-banner h2 {
    text-shadow: green;
}
```

That means: "Set `text-shadow: green` on all `h2` elements that are descendants of an element with *both* the classes `dark` and `ux-banner`.

Alternately, if you want to be somewhat specific:

```
.dark.ux-banner div h2 {
    text-shadow: green;
}
```

(Only applies to `h2` elements within `div` elements within `.dark.ux-banner` elements.)

Or hyper-specific:

```
.dark.ux-banner > div > h2 {
    text-shadow: green;
}
```

(Only applies to `h2` elements that are *direct children* of `div` elements that are *direct children* of `.dark.ux-banner` elements.)

The key bit above is really that `.dark.ux-banner` (with no spaces) means "an element with *both* of these classes." The rest is just descendant or child combinators.

Comment: would it not be 
     .dark.ux-banner div h2
if I wanted to target the h2 element?

Comment: @T.J.Crowder may I know why have you written .dark.ux-banner I mean to ask why two periods in class name?

Comment: This is an excellent explanation of css selectors. I could have used this when I was trying to learn how all of this works....

Comment: @T.J.Crowder Great answer. Just one follow-up question. If a space is given between `.dark` and `.ux-banner` example being `.dark .ux-banner h2{text-shadow:green;}` then how would I interpret this CSS?

Comment: @Geek: The space would change the compound class selector into a descendant combinator. (I didn't make that word up, that's what the spec calls them -- ugh!) The meaning would become: ""Set `text-shadow: green` on all `h2` elements that are descendants of an element with the `ux-banner` class which is, in turn, a descendant of an element with the `dark` class. E.g., an `h2` in a `.ux-banner` in a `.dark`, rather than an `h2` in a `.ux-banner.dark`.

Answer (score 3):

```
.dark.ux-banner h2 { text-shadow:green; }
```

http://jsfiddle.net/YjGhw/

Answer (score 3):

You will need

```
.dark.ux-banner h2{
     text-shadow:green;
}
```

What this does is selects the elements that have the class `.dark` then checks if it has the class `.ux-banner` then selects all `h2` inside that

Answer (score 0):

Here is the demo http://jsfiddle.net/tFScD/2/

```
      <div class="demo">
        <div class="the attributed classes of this element will vary">
         <h2>TARGET THIS ELEMENT
           </h2>
          </div>
      </div>


  .demo div h2{
         text-shadow:2px 2px green;
     }
```

Answer (score 0):

It's simple. Just use the following:

```
.dark.ux-banner h2 { 
    text-shadow:green; 
}
```

This means every `h2` element inside an element with these classes will have the `text-shadow:green` propperty no matter if the `h2` element is inside a `div` or not.

```
<div class="dark ux-banner">
    <div class="the attributed classes of this element will vary">
        <h2>
            TARGET THIS ELEMENT
        </h2>
    </div>
</div>

or

<div class="dark ux-banner">
    <h2>
        TARGET THIS ELEMENT
    </h2>
</div>

will work the same ;)
```

Answer (score 0):

```
.dark.ux-banner h2{
     text-shadow:0 0 4px green;
}
```

the markup

```
<div class="dark ux-banner">
      <div class="the attributed classes of this element will vary">
           <h2>TARGET THIS ELEMENT
           </h2>
      </div>
 </div>
```

demo: http://jsfiddle.net/cQcbp/

[image]